# Why is the sum() sql function not working?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I am trying to write a code that collects all the data in a column named AMOUNT in a table named PERSON and I used the function sum() and I got an error java.sql.SQLException: There is no column named: SUM(AMOUNT).

my code is:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   Connection con = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   try{
       String sql ="SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM PERSON";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Invoices","user1","user1");
       ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs=ps.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()){
       String sum=rs.getString("SUM(AMOUNT)");
       jLabel3.setText(sum);
       }
    }
       catch(Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error is

> java.sql.SQLException: There is no column named: SUM(AMOUNT).

Comment: my guess is you 'll need something like "rs.getString("SUM");" instead of "rs.getString("SUM (AMOUNT)");"

Comment: or `rs.getString(1)` (value of first column in result set)

Comment: Why do you think your result set has a column called `SUM(AMOUNT)`? That is the expression you used, not a column label (some database systems may generate an implicit label for these types of expressions, but they are unlikely to use the expression itself).

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
String sql ="SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM PERSON";
```

as

```
String sql ="SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS sumAmount FROM PERSON";  // Use a alias.
```

Then

```
String sum=rs.getString("sumAmount");
```